# I'm trying to get post array value in controller

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I'm new in jQuery and Codeigniter. All I m trying is to get post value to controller function, which I got from jQuery `serialize()`, but I'm getting error saying undefined variable. How can I get the value in controller of checkin and checkout? Here is my code...

this is view:

```html
//$key i'm passing here is an array

<input name ="checkin<?php echo $key;?>" type="textbox" class="TextBox1" value="<?php echo $in; ?>"/>
<input name ="checkout<?php echo $k;?>" type="textbox"  class="TextBox2" value="<?php echo $out; ?>"/>
<script>
$("input").blur(function () {
    var form_data = $("#employee_2").find('input').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo site_url(" HomeController / calculate_time_lap "); ?>",
        type: 'POST',
        data: form_data,
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result);
            //$('input').closest('tr').find('.TextBox3').val(result);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
</script>
```

Controller
the `$value` I'm getting is null ....

```
public function calculate_time_lap() {
    $formate = "%h:%i";
    $checkin['val'] = $this->input->post('checkin');
    //is my post 'checkin' here is null... 
    foreach ($val as $value)
    {
        echo $value;   
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `#employee_2`, is it a form?

Comment: #employee_2 is id for a row...

Comment: What's the complete error? `undefined variable` Could be everything.

Comment: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()...

Comment: Undefined variable: val... is the post value('checkin')null??

Answer (score 0):

try this 
HTML:

```
<input name ="checkin" type="textbox" class="TextBox1" value="<?php echo $in; ?>"/>
<input name ="checkout" type="textbox"  class="TextBox2" value="<?php echo $out; ?>"/>
```

you have to use the same name in controller which you used in html.

i think you used =>

```
name ="checkin<?php echo $key;?>
```

in html but are calling with just $this->input->post('checkin').
so you do not get anything.  if $key=1  the call in controller like $this->input->post('checkin1')

Comment: foreach ($val as $value) here $val is what? you can use for loop to to get iteratively get value and save like  $checkin['val'+i] = $this->input->post('checkin'+i);

Comment: val is the variable i passed for post...here  in controller....$checkin['val'] = $this->input->post('checkin');

Comment: you get nothing for $val .you can simply echo $checkin['val'] to be sure what you got?

Comment: again the value i get is null... :(

Comment: just try with one textbox named with checkin see what happens

Comment: i tried it works when doing $this->input->post('checkin1') but i need to get all the value ...

Comment: Try with input type="text". I am not sure that 'textbox' is valid input type.